# Identifying or getting any info on this strange German oscilloscope

Tags: oscilloscope, cathode-ray-oscilloscope

I have this old oscilloscope that seems to be made in Germany but all the knobs are in English. Yet the names and plates on the thing are in German and seems to a German manufacturer in the 60s. But there’s a date of 30-3-55 which is before any of their devices have been documented. I’m curious on any information about this thing.

[image: Oscilloscope image 1]

[image: Oscilloscope image 2]

[image: Oscilloscope image 3]

([Original images](https://imgur.com/a/1izsDgw))

Answer (score 0):

It seems that was an engineer, Günther Haeberlein, who started a company in Munich. The house at [that address]( seems to still be office spaces, with a shop on the ground floor. My expectation is that this is the same house.

I also found some [radios](https://www.gfgf.org/Forum/index.php?t=msg&th=3&) that were manufactured there in 1953, so the date sounds plausible.